My sentiment analysis is giving wrong predictions
I have a dataframe that contains two columns: tweets and labels(offensive language, hate speech, no hate and offensive).
I cleaned the tweets and created my model.
But after modelling, all my test texts are giving same prediction results: "No Hate and Offensive"
# Cleaning my text
def clean_text(text):
    text = str(text).lower()
    text = re.sub('\[.*?\]', '', text)
    text = re.sub('https?://\S+|www\.\S+', '', text)
    text = re.sub('<.*?>+', '', text)
    text = re.sub('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation), '', text)
    text = re.sub('\n', '', text)
    text = re.sub('\w*\d\w*', '', text)
    text = [word for word in text.split(' ') if word not in stopword]
    text = "".join(text)
    text = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in text.split(' ')]
    text = "".join(text)
    
    return text

data["tweet"] = data["tweet"].apply(clean_text)


#Converting my columns to array
import numpy as np
x = np.array(data["tweet"])
y = np.array(data["labels"])


# Fiting the tweet column for modelling
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
count_vec = CountVectorizer()
X = count_vec.fit_transform(x)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 42)


from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

dc_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dc_tree.fit(X_train, y_train)

##Testing my Model
test_text = "Kill all of them and burn it down"
test_data = count_vec.transform([test_text]).toarray()

print(dc_tree.predict(test_data)) 
#Output: ['No Hate and Offensive'] #Expectation: ['Hate Speech']


test_text = "practice love and patience to live a good life!"
test_data2 = count_vec.transform([test_text]).toarray()
print(dc_tree.predict(test_data2)) 
#Output: ['No Hate and Offensive']



I would suspect your model is overfit on the training data - did you check train vs. test scores?
Don't use DecisionTreeClassifier without setting the max_depth parameter, otherwise you are almost guaranteed to overfit. Alternatively, you may want to look into classification approaches which are less prone to overfitting like a random forest
